# How to create alignment text in multiple <p/> tags and <em/> in HTML

Tags: html

I am display two rows of text, I used `</em>` since I want aligntext1 to have red color only.

```html
<div>
<p> tesing12345678910 <em className="text-read-50">aligntext1</em>
<br/> tes123 <em className="text-read-50">aligntext2</em> </p>         
</div>
```

How can I create something like this, making aligntext to be the same "column".

```
tesing12345678910 aligntext1
tes123            aligntext2
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the <table> tag?

Comment: Read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-table/info

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```css
.row{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.column{
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.text-red-50{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p> tesing12345678910 </p>
    <p> test123 </p>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <p class="text-red-50"> aligntext1 </p>
    <p class="text-red-50"> aligntext2 </p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to learn more about flex container, like how to add space between the columns and else, here is a [link for docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp)

Answer (score 0):

as jonas said. you can use table tag without border.

```css
.text-read-50 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>tesing12345678910</td>
      <td><em class="text-read-50">aligntext1</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tes123</td>
      <td><em class="text-read-50">aligntext2</em></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

you can also omit the  tag and move the CSS class to `<td>` if you just need to color the aligntext without making the text italic.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be tabular data so a table wouldn't be appropriate.